# How to run roles based on user provided variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a playbook with 3 roles:
view-img
view-app
view-src

I want to run only the role based on the user provided variable. If user runs playbbook as:
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory -e "step=view-img"

I have defined step variable in my all.yml with default value.

and I have written conditional when statement as below:

when step == view-img

But still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Use [import_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html#ansible-builtin-import-role-import-a-role-into-a-play) or [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#ansible-builtin-include-role-load-and-execute-a-role), e.g.

```yaml
  - import_role:
      name: "{{ step }}"
```